# configure mod_rewrite redirect to sub-directory, to display only domain as URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following mod_rewrite to redirect from the root domain to the sub-directory `shows/`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]
```

It is now displaying the URL as `http://www.example.com/shows/`

I would like to amend, or append, the mod_rewrite to display the URL as it would have *before* the redirect, for example... `http://www.example.com`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lines 2 and 3.

Just

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /shows
```

will do the job I believe.

The problem is that queries were matching the R=301, which is a permanent redirect.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I wouldn't *need* the `RewriteBase /` right? But your answer doesn't seem to be showing `http://example.com`. It's still showing the `/shows/` on the end. Was your answer suppose to have that result?